# Selecting all text in Vi/Vim through PuTTY

Tags: shell, vi

I  need to select the text in a log file (~900 lines) and paste it into a normal text file.

However, I am on my server via PuTTY so when I do `:%y+ or gg"+yG` it does not let me paste it.

By any chance is there a way to select text from Vi through PuTTY?

Comment: There's probably a better way to do it: what is your criteria for selecting the text? I'm guessing sed is a better tool than vi.

Comment: Are you running putty on windows?

Comment: Are you using ssh to connect?

Comment: putty on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ssh access to the file, can you use SFTP to just download the log file?